# Getting an Uncaught Reference Error with no syntax errors

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

I'm trying to make a simple JQuery JSON call with some HTML, JS, and PHP, but it seems like there's a bug in my createBuilding() function. One of the first thing the function does is create an alert box and not even that shows up. When I check the Javascript console I get Uncaught Reference Error. I made a JS Fiddle to see if anyone can help!

http://jsfiddle.net/LpFTj/1/

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to confining your function to the scope of DOM Ready event .. So you cannot access outside of .. Also a type in this element  `buildingType`

```
var buildingFinalType = document.getElementById('builtingType').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `createBuilding` outside `$(document).ready`. Since it is defined in a function it is not available outside the scope of that function i.e. not globally available.

Comment: @Vikram Why would you want to?

Comment: Yes you can, but it must defined as a jquery plugin and accessed this way.